# Table view basics and appearance like MS Excel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am new to Objective-C programming. Please help me understand how to insert data into a table view with a visual style similar to MS Excel.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot look exactly like you want it to, because tables in MS Excel and on the iPhone are different.

The table view on iOS has two items which you can configure to show data -- a datasoure and a delegate.

If you can fetch all the data from MS Excel in such a way that you can access any particular data just by knowing its row and column, then that data can be shown in your table view.

In a table view there is a concept of `NSIndexPath`, which is a structure of row numbers and corresponding section number.
Now let's suppose that there is situation that your Excel document has records of one hundred students and each record has three fields: name, age, sex. In this situation you'll make a table view with one hundred sections and three rows for each section.

Now suppose you have a view controller named `myViewController` to show this table view, named `myTableView`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    myTableView.datasource = self; 
    myTableView.delegate = self;
}
```

Now before you can do that you need to do the following in the MyViewController.h file

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
```

Now suppose you have an array named `allStudents` containing objects of class `Student` which has three properties:

```
NSString * name;

NSUInteger * age;

BOOL male; // yes if sex is male else NO
```

Now you need to implement the table view datasource and delegate methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [allStudents count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Student * current = [allStudents objectAtIndex:NSIndexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = current.name;
    if( current.male ) {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dyr M",current.age];
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dyr F",current.age];
    }


    return cell;
}
```

You can access different properties of your table view to make it behave differently.

I hope this helped you.

Comment: amit thanks for giving this code.But i am having one doubt wht student*current.please send me reply.thanks again for giving me reply

Comment: when i am accessing this code i am getting this error " Unknown 'section' class method"
 can u please give me  guidance  for rectifying this error .please give me suggistion

Comment: Please use big-boy language when writing answers. Type out the full word "you" instead of "u". It's only two more characters. It's not that hard.

Comment: Student is a demo class with three properties namely 
NSString* name;

NSUInteger* age;

BOOL male; // yes if sex is male else NO

and you are getting that error because there is a mistake in m code Insteade of
Student* current = [allStudents objectAtIndex:NSIndexPath.section];
write
Student* current = [allStudents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

Comment: @Code Gray: Since when is coding big-boy business? The last coders I met where Star Wars and Star Trek fans, played pen and paper RPGs and had their clothes washed by their moms. Thats not really "big-boy".